# Create Site Using Template GROUP#0 Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have created a SharePoint site and configured the site via the UI, I am now looking to re-engineer this into a PowerShell script so it can be used across multiple environments.

When I create the site via the UI, I am using the Standard Teams template.

When running `Get-SPOSite`, the template ID which is brought back is 'GROUP#0'.

I am trying to create a site using `New-SPOSite`, however, when I use this template ID, I receive the below error:

```
New-SPOSite -Url "$SharePointURL/sites/$SiteName" -Owner $UserEmail -Template "GROUP#0" -Title "Test Site" -StorageQuota '1000' -CompatibilityLevel 15 -LocaleId 1033 -Verbose

The web template GROUP#0 is not available for sites on this tenant.
```

`Get-SPOWebTemplate` does not include GROUP#0

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Try running `Get-SPOWebTemplate` to list the available templates and check what the actual names listed are

Comment: Ive done that already, GROUP#0 does not exist...

Comment: Alright, now you know why :) Is the teams template listed in the output?

Comment: There is Teams templates, but none of them match what I have deployed...I don't get it.

I have tried all 3 templates via PowerShell, none of them match what I have in the UI.